# Not able to set cookies on Instagram

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, instagram

I am making a chrome-extension and trying to set cookies onto every page I visit. The cookies are getting set on every website I have tried except [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/).

I have confirmed that the content script is running on Instagram, but the following standard 'set cookie' function is not doing anything when the script is being run on Instagram

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*60*1000));
    let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Comment: It means the site either clears the cookie or your browser is configured not to remember cookies on this site.

Comment: @wOxxOm right, so is there any general solution to this that you know of, incase I want to put this extension up on the chrome store?

Comment: I'm not sure what use case you have, but you could save the data for all sites locally in the extension. If you're not changing a cookie that the site uses, what use case can you have in that case?

Comment: @Weetz I basically wanted a storage system that could store a parameter temporarily for a given amount of duration, and cookies was the only thing I could think of, which I could make expire after the required duration. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, I would just store it with [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-local) and save each site with a timestamp for when the object should be removed.

Comment: @Weetz yup, I was a bit lazy to do that implementation because the storage won't get cleared on it's own, but now I have ditched cookies and chrome local storage is working perfectly well! Thank you again :)